# Win32 C++ : Parent controls is drawn on top of children

Tags: c++, windows, win32gui

I'm currently writing a GUI application using a self-made wrapper for Win32 windows and controls. I have made a custom class, which is supposed to act as a container for children controls. The problem is that my custom control is drawn on top of the children controls, which makes them invisible.

I've added the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag to my container, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you looked into "z-order"? It's been a while that I did classical Windows programming, but that's what has popped into mind as I read the question

Comment: Oh ok, I'm so stupid. I just used SetWindowPos() in my method to add a child control, and I made it so it gets inserted after the parent control. And that did it!

Now I just have one problem : I have to give a new position and a new size for the child control, except I have already initialized them. Is there an equivalent function to insert a control after another without having to move it or resize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeromy Adofo pointed out, the problem was related to Z-ordering.

I used `SetWindowPos()` (MSDN page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos)) and passed the first two arguments like this : `SetWindowPos(childHwnd, parentHwnd, ...);` and it worked.

Just another thing, `SetWindowPos()` asks for the child's position and size. If these values are already set for you, and you don't want to pass them again, use the flag combination `SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE` and set the position and size parameters to zero.